# Flutter Call Set State from another Class

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am build a page where there are buttons that will be dynamic options. When you select the option it highlights it, adds the widget to a list and then I want it to display the list in the top part of the page.

I can view the list in debug mode, so I know when the button is pressed it is being added to the list.

What is not happening however, is the state of the page is not refreshing to be visible by the user.

How do I have the button also set the state of the other widget to view the list?

[image]

[image]

So here is the first page. This page has the code that is passing the data along to the Tag When the tag is presssed and item is added to the digitalHash List, which is in the first expanded

Comments added

```
    class Digital extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _DigitalState createState() => _DigitalState();
    }

    class _DigitalState extends State<Digital> {
      final postRefresh = ChangeNotifier();

      bool digitalSelected = false;
      List digitalHash = new List();

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff0E0E0F),
          appBar: AppBar(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Color(0xffff9900),
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "#", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Color(0xffff9900), fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
                ),
                Text("digital", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
//this is where the list is being displayed
                    for (var digitalHashs in digitalHash) Text(digitalHashs, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),),
                    ],
                  ),
                  color: Colors.blue
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 5),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Tag(
                        tag: "#Digital",
                        isSelected: digitalSelected,
                        list: digitalHash,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I wanted to be able to reuse the Tag... here is the Tag element

```
class Tag extends StatefulWidget {
  final String tag;
  bool isSelected;
  List list;
  Widget page;


  Tag({Key key, @required this.tag, @required this.isSelected, this.list, this.page}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TagState createState() => _TagState();
}

class _TagState extends State<Tag> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.isSelected ? Color(0xffff9900) : Colors.black,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          _handleOnPressed();
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  widget.tag,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20, color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
                )),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                child: AnimatedIcon(
                  icon: AnimatedIcons.home_menu,
                  progress: _animationController,
                  color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleOnPressed() {
    setState(() {
      widget.isSelected = !widget.isSelected;
      widget.isSelected
          ? _animationController.forward()
          : _animationController.reverse();
      widget.isSelected ? widget.list.add(widget.tag) : widget.list.remove(widget.tag);
      print(widget.list);
    });
  }
}
```

There is no error the digital hash list is just not updating when i push the tag. But the tag DOES highlight.

I am just trying to update the one expanded section so that it displays the list.

Comment: can you please post the code to that? need some more information on what are you using where etc.

Comment: Please post code and any error logs that pop up in the terminal when you run this, so we can better help.

Comment: Ok code updated

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below  
I also provide working demo 
In DigitalStage add two function for add/remove list 
Use `final key = new GlobalKey<DigitalState>();` you can call these two function from Tag

code snippet

```
final key = new GlobalKey<DigitalState>();

class Digital extends StatefulWidget {
  Digital({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
...
    void add(String tag) {
    setState(() {
      digitalHash.add(tag);
    });

  }

  void remove(String tag) {
    setState(() {
      digitalHash.remove(tag);
    });

  }
...
widget.isSelected
          ?  key.currentState.add(widget.tag)
          : key.currentState.remove(widget.tag);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Digital(key: key),
    );
  }
}


final key = new GlobalKey<DigitalState>();

class Digital extends StatefulWidget {
  Digital({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DigitalState createState() => DigitalState();
}

class DigitalState extends State<Digital> {
  final postRefresh = ChangeNotifier();

  bool digitalSelected = false;
  List digitalHash = new List();

  void add(String tag) {
    setState(() {
      digitalHash.add(tag);
    });

  }

  void remove(String tag) {
    setState(() {
      digitalHash.remove(tag);
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        //key: key,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff0E0E0F),
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Color(0xffff9900),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "#",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Color(0xffff9900),
                    fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
              ),
              Text(
                "digital",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
//this is where the list is being displayed
                    for (var digitalHashs in digitalHash)
                      Text(
                        digitalHashs,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 5),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Tag(
                    tag: "#Digital",
                    isSelected: digitalSelected,
                    list: digitalHash,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]));
  }
}

class Tag extends StatefulWidget {
  final String tag;
  bool isSelected;
  List list;
  Widget page;

  Tag(
      {Key key,
      @required this.tag,
      @required this.isSelected,
      this.list,
      this.page})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TagState createState() => _TagState();
}

class _TagState extends State<Tag> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.isSelected ? Color(0xffff9900) : Colors.black,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          _handleOnPressed();
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  widget.tag,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
                )),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                child: AnimatedIcon(
                  icon: AnimatedIcons.home_menu,
                  progress: _animationController,
                  color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleOnPressed() {
    setState(() {
      widget.isSelected = !widget.isSelected;
      widget.isSelected
          ? _animationController.forward()
          : _animationController.reverse();
      widget.isSelected
          ?  key.currentState.add(widget.tag)
          : key.currentState.remove(widget.tag);
      print(widget.list);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an error when I click the button. flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: The method 'add' was called on null.

Comment: So I went back and tried to play around with this. The List is not getting anything added to it. I was trying to make the Tag class reusable since I am going to have many different types of Tags to add to the list eventually. So from what I am gathering from the error I am not actually adding anything to the List.

Comment: Also, I copy and pasted your code into a new project and it works somewhat, the remove does not work, it just adds it, a 2nd click should remove it. But this means that there is something with the way that I am building it. So I am going to look at that. Do you know why the remove would not work? the isSelected is not being changed from true/false form what I can see as well.

Comment: I have the true/false working, and I am still getting the error... so it is something that I am missing, but when i copied it over into a new project, it is working exactly as I want.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. So its the global key, so let me explain this, there is a main page that uses a constructor to build a subpage, where Digital is there created.There will eventually be a TON of categories, and I wanted to reuse it.. so the Global key is getting used by Multiple widgets. So for Example Main Page -> Categories -> Sub Categories -> Digital - > Tags but it could also be Main Page -> Categories -> Sub Categories -> Art -> Tags

Comment: I have opened my GitHub if you want to poke around and see what I have done and help me correct my problem. I am at a loss.. I am still a newbit programmer. https://github.com/BND10706/tags

Comment: Global key can link to widget. so you can call function inside widget with global key. You can assign each widget a global key if you need. I would suggest simplify and post to another question. so more people can help you.